# The use of $TM_FILEPATH with Python in TextMate

Tags: python, textmate

I'm making a TextMate command with python. The job is to get the current file name, get the html file name by changing the extension name, and run safari to open the html file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os.path
import os

oldName = $TM_FILEPATH
(name, ext) = os.path.splitext(oldName)
rename = name + ".html"
os.system("open -a Safari %s" % rename)
```

The problem is that python doesn't seem to understand $TM_FILENAME, as I get the following error.

```
File "/tmp/temp_textmate.A9q270", line 5 oldName = $TM_FILEPATH ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's wrong? How can I use $TM_FILEPATH just like I do with bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
os.environ["TM_FILEPATH"]
```

(`os.environ` is how you access environment variables in Python. It's a dictionary-like object.)

Comment: Not a dictionary, but a mapping.

Comment: Dictionary-like object, I mean to say.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `os.environ['TM_FILEPATH']` instead.